# How do I make this into a table output?

Tags: java, dice

The problem is asking me to roll two dice and print their output individually in two separate columns and then create a third column for the sum of two rolls.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class DiceRolls {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Dice 1\tDice 2");
        Random ran = new Random();

        int numberOne;
        for (int x = 0; x < 7; x++) {
            numberOne = ran.nextInt(6) + 1;
            System.out.println(numberOne);
        }

        int numberTwo;
        for (int y = 0; y < 7; y++) {
            numberTwo = ran.nextInt(6) + 1;
            System.out.println("    " + numberTwo);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are thinking about this the wrong way and attempting to loop over all rolls of one die, **THEN** over the other die.  If you instead attempt to roll both dice at the same time, then add them and print the output it makes things a lot simpler:

```
    //How many runs you want
    int numRuns = 7;

    for (int x = 0; x < numRuns; x++) {
        Random ran = new Random();
        int dieOne = ran.nextInt(6) + 1;
        int dieTwo = ran.nextInt(6) + 1;
        System.out.format("| Die 1:%3d| Die 2:%3d| Total:%3d|\n", dieOne, dieTwo, dieOne + dieTwo);
    }
```

This code will roll two dice 7 times and add them together.  You can change the value of `numRuns` to change number of times it is run.  You can then use `System.out.format` or `String.format` to create a formatted output.

What `String.format` or `System.out.format` does is basically use `%3d` to put the variables, for example `dieOne`, inside of the `String` in a formatted manner.  This example of `%3d` can be broken down into 3 basic parts.

- The `3` stands for number of ***characters*** to allow the variable
  to use, with the unused characters to be filled with extra spaces.
- The `d` is the type of variable (in this case an `int`)
- The `%` is used to signify that there is a variable in the `String`
  at that location.

So in summation: `%3d` is used to set the values of `dieOne`, `dieTwo`, and `dieOne + dieTwo` respectively into the `String` as an `int` each with a total of 3 ***characters***.

In the edited example below, `%4d`, `%4d`, `%5d` have 4, 4, and 5 total ***characters*** that `dieOne`, `dieTwo`, and `dieOne + dieTwo` are set to respectively.  The number of characters chosen were used to match the width of the headers of `Die1`, `Die2`, and `Total`.

**EDIT:**  If you want it to look more like a table you can print it like this:

```
    //How many runs you want
    int numRuns = 7;

    System.out.println("-----------------");
    System.out.println("|Die1|Die2|Total|");
    System.out.println("-----------------");
    for (int x = 0; x < numRuns; x++) {
        Random ran = new Random();
        int dieOne = ran.nextInt(6) + 1;
        int dieTwo = ran.nextInt(6) + 1;
        System.out.format("|%4d|%4d|%5d|\n", dieOne, dieTwo, dieOne + dieTwo);
    }
    System.out.println("-----------------");
```

Comment: What does the last line do    "System.out.format("|%4d|%4d|%5d|\n", dieOne, dieTwo, dieOne + dieTwo); "

Comment: @Cleo Added an explanation to the body.

Comment: 4,4,5 is the spaces between what? Also why did you have to write dieOne, dieTwo and then dieOne + dieTwo?